# Injecting property using @Value to abstract class

Tags: spring

I have an abstract class in which I am trying to use the @Value annotation to inject value from a property file

```
public abstract class Parent {
     @Value ("${shared.val}")
     private String sharedVal;

     public Parent() {
        //perform common action using sharedVal
     }

}

@Component
public class ChildA extends Parent {
     Param a1;
     @Autowired
     public ChildA (Param a1) {
        super();
        this.a1 = a1;
     }
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException since sharedVal is not set.  I tried adding @Component stereotype on the abstract class and still the same thing.

Can I inject value into abstract class this way?  If not how can accomplish this?

Comment: How is your subclass instantiated?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you'll find the sharedVal *is* being set, but you're trying to use it too soon in the constructor. The constructor is being called (must be called) before Spring injects the value using the `@Value` annotation.

Instead of processing the value in the constructor, try a `@PostContruct` method instead, eg:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    //perform common action using sharedVal
 }
```

(or alternatively, implement Spring's InitializingBean interface).

Comment: The earliest you should touch any injected value is in a post-construct method; the state of properties earlier in the lifecycle is undefined (well, typically `null` or zero to be pedantic).

Comment: And how could I get the value defined in my porperties file? @Value ("${shared.val}")

Comment: since java 9+, the annotation is deprecated, need to import javax.annotation javax.annotation-api

Answer (score 5):

> Can I inject value into abstract class this way?

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, so nothing can be injected into the abstract class. Instead , you should inject the value to its concrete subclass.

Make sure your concrete subclass is marked as `@Component` stereotype and being "component scanning" by Spring . `@Component` on the abstract class is not needed as it cannot be instantiated.

---

Update :  I finally figure out that you are trying to access the injected value inside the constructor but found that the value is not set.  It is because Spring will inject the value after the bean is instantiated . So if constructor injection is not used , the injected value cannot be accessed inside the constructor . You can use `@PostContruct` or implementing `InitializingBean` as suggested by Matt.

Following shows if XML configuration is used :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xxxxx.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />


<bean id="parent" class="pkg.Parent" abstract="true" init-method="postConstruct">
    <property name="sharedVal" value="${shared.val}" />
</bean>


<bean id="child" class="pkg.ChildA" parent="parent">
```

Perform your common action using `sharedVal` inside `Parent#postConstruct()`

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there is a way to do it since via xml, you could create an bean as abstract.  But this does make sense, since Spring have no way to initialize the abstract class, value can not be injected.  I can only think of using Property object to load my property file, and obtain the key.  I was hoping to avoid this by using the @Value annotation

Comment: I think this answer is misleading - Spring will in fact inject values for properties defined on abstract base classes when you're using autowiring.

Comment: @MattR . Yes . Spring will inject the value of the properties defined on the abstract class into  the concrete subclass but not into the abstract class as  abstract class cannot be instantiated  . Please let me know which part of my answer you think is misleading .

Comment: @KenChan yes of course, but the question was clearly asking why his code wasn't working. He was wrong about why (nothing to do with abstract classes), so while your answer is factual it has left him with the wrong impression that his code can't be made to work (it does actually work, he's just accessing the value too early).

Comment: @MattR But I see him asking "Can I inject value into abstract class this way? If not how can accomplish this?"

Comment: @KenChan yes the wording was bad, I give him the benefit of the doubt though and guess he meant property _defined on_ the abstract base class - I just hope he comes back and reads both answers before refactoring his config :-)

Comment: @KenChan btw, I think your XML here will have the same problem as the original code - it will still be trying to use the value in the constructor of `Parent` before `sharedVal` is set...

Comment: @MattR . Yes you are right . I miss to notice that he wants to perform some action using `sharedVal` inside the abstract class 's constructor

Comment: Thanks guys, I posted the question after a few hours of tinkering, the promptly fell asleep.  Both of your solution works, and I went with the annotation route.