# Annotations declared in Abstract Class not being loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, annotations

I have a Dynamic Web Project created in Eclipse (Juno) using Spring/Maven/Weblogic. I also have an Abstract class into which I inject a property (on the setter) via a properties file. The annotation used is @Value(value="${some.property}").
For some strange reason, when I deploy this project via maven to weblogic, the property gets injected for the concrete class that etends this Abstract class. But when I deploy this project directly onto weblogic via the Server -> Add Deployment, it fails to inject the property. In fact it does inject properties for all other annotations on the concrete class but ignores any annotations for the abstract class.
So basically this has nothing to do with coding but seems like some kind of config problem. Has anyone encountered something similar. Thanks.

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    @Value(value="${myproperty1}")
    public void setMyValue(String myValue) {
        log.debug("setMyValue({})", myValue);
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
}

public class MyConcrete {
    @Value(value="${myproperty2}")
    public void setMyValue2(String myValue2) {
        log.debug("setMyValue2({})", myValue2);
        this.myValue2 = myValue2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961257/injecting-property-using-value-to-abstract-class

Comment: Kinda but not exactly. In my case I am not trying to use the value within the constructor. I do have "@Scheduled" annotation on one of the methods on the concrete class which in turn uses this value. Could it be that in this case, the "@Scheduled" annotation supercedes the "@Value" annotation? But even if it did, then why would it work when I "maven deploy" it to the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The thing is that this particular bean has @Scheduled annotation and hence does not qualify for Bean Post Processing. Since the properties via @Value are set during this phase, they are skipped. Instead I shifted the bean creation into my application context xml file and set the properties from there eg.

```
<bean id="myConcrete" class="some.package.MyConcrete"
    p:value="${myproperty1}"
/>
```

Now the properties are getting injected during normal bean lifecycle i.e. after Instantiation but before Bean Post Processor.